# Extend the JQuery Sorting in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to extend the JQuery DataTable plugin as because I don't want to modify the existing plugin, as if newer version is coming, is not replace on what I have right now in the plugin.

So, what I want to do is I want to modify the order array in JQuery DataTable for not only getting the direction of order and the column index <-- this already exists in the JQuery DataTable, but I want to make it to have the direction of order, the column index, and the data attribute for the correspondent column.

The following JQuery DataTable Sort that I want extend is the following:

```
if ( features.bSort ) {
            $.each( sort, function ( i, val ) {
                d.order.push( { column: val.col, dir: val.dir } );

                param( 'iSortCol_'+i, val.col );
                param( 'sSortDir_'+i, val.dir );
            } );

            param( 'iSortingCols', sort.length );
        }
```

which I would add 1 more object inside an order array like:

```
if ( features.bSort ) {
            $.each( sort, function ( i, val ) {
                d.order.push( { column: val.col, name: "(Get the data attribute of the correspondent column on the particular datatable that it is being ordered.)", dir: val.dir } );

                param( 'iSortCol_'+i, val.col );
                param( 'sSortDir_'+i, val.dir );
            } );

            param( 'iSortingCols', sort.length );
        }
```

However, I do not know on how to extend the JQuery DataTable plugin and I want it to when the JQuery DataTable is being ordered, then the plugin that I wrote will be executed as well, as there are a lot of DataTable that is being used in the project, so I do not want it to write it 1 by 1 on where the JQuery DataTable is being used.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You would need to write your own plug in. This describes how to do it: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

Comment: What is the reason behind to add the `name` attribute for the order?

Comment: @rf1234, thanks, will look into it.

Comment: @samabcde, the reason is because the JQuery DataTable returns the int as the Column Index and string as the Column Direction. for the Column Direction, it is okay, but for the Column Index, it is not okay as my project is getting the data to the DataTable from Server Side (with Server Side option enabled in JQuery DataTable and with pagination (only retrieve 10 rows per page) ) as the data is huge, and whenever on the UI do the sorting (ascending or descending), it needs to go to the Server Side to query the data again with the ordering

Comment: @samabcde, if the Column Index matches with the Select Statement (for example first column is Address, and on the UI for the first column is Address as well, then it is okay. But what about if on the Select Statement is not Address, means the sorting is wrong. As because the SQL will try to `order by 0 asc`, which the 0 is something else other than Address (which displayed on UI)

Comment: As I know, the `columns` array is also send to server side, you can try to get the `data` attribute from the `columns` by the index.

Comment: @samabcde, let me try it and will let you know later. Thanks

Comment: Hi @samabcde, as I have tried, the columns did contains the header name of the correspondent column that the table is being ordered. However, it is only contains the column's header name and so on which do not contains the `data` attribute of the correspondent column. how can I get the `data` attribute of the correspondent column then from the plugin or extend from the plugin and be called directly once the datatable column is being ordered? Thanks

Comment: Please check the http request, the `columns` should contains `data`, I have checked that the `data` attribute exist in this site when searching https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Hi @samabcde, how do you check the `data` attribute exists in the link that you provided above? as when I went into there and inspect element, there is no `data-` attribute being predefined on the elements within the table. I mean for what I want, let's say that the first column have `data-sort-name` and the value for it is `Leonhardt`. then when I click the search for the first column, it will get the `data-sort-name` value. which is `Leonhardt`

Comment: Please take a look on the screen capture https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VOxg.png, to see if I misunderstand your problem.

Comment: Hi @samabcde, seems you are misunderstood my question and what I intended to do. Please take a look at the following link:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQBqpr, please let me know if you are not clear. Thanks a lot. Basically, I want to retrieve the `data-sort-name` as part of the `order array` in the JQuery DataTable plugin, so that whenever I initialized the DataTable, and sort the particular column in the JQuery DataTable, it will be executed and the array will contains: `columnName: (string value based on the data-sort-name)`

Comment: continued from the above @samabcde. So the array will contains: `column: (int value), columnName: (string value). dir: (string value)`, which the `columnName` object will be added into the `order array`. But I want it to be extend from the JQuery DataTable plugin, so whenever I initialized and click the row for the ordering, it then the `order array` will contains `column, columnName and dir` like I have described in the question above. Thanks a lot!